# Positioning grid items in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, css-grid

im trying to get my "Home" and "Clock" link up inside the navigation-bar. I am clueless why the CSS i wrote doesnt solve this issue. Can someone help me out? Ive tried using the grid property for the children of the navigation-bar, but they seem to not fit. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<div class="container">
<div class="header">Home</div>

<div class="navigation">
Navigation
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Clock</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content-large">
Overview

<div class="grid-item">
  <form>
    <button class="cal_btn" formaction="">Calendar</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <form>
    <button class="cal_btn" formaction="">Show</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <form>
    <button class="cal_btn" formaction="/tagung/">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <form>
    <button class="cal_btn" formaction="/cal/">Edit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
  <form>
    <button class="cal_btn" formaction="">Delete</button>
  </form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-small">. . .</div>
<div class="content-small">. . .</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS file below

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;

  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 1fr 1fr 100px;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header,
.navigation,
.footer,
.content-large,
.content-small {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container > .header {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
.container > .navigation {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.navigation ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

  grid-column: 1/4;
  font-size: large;
}
.nav-element {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.container > .content-large {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.grid-item {
  padding: 1px;
}

.nav-item {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.container > .cal_btn {
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.cal_btn:hover {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
.container > .footer {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}
```

Thanks in advance!
P.S. Ive added a link to my Codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-meadow-oynldu?file=/styles.css:0-1249).

Comment: I don't see "Clock" in your sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you are not getting the desired layout is that `display: grid;` rule for `.navigation ul` makes the `ul` a block element, which gets the whole width of its parent. There may be various ways to achieve this. A solution with minimal changes to your code is replacing `display: grid;` with

```
display: inline-grid;
width: 200px;
```

Of course you can adjust the width as you wish.

Comment: you mean changing the display rule inside the container?

Comment: My bad, I did not realize there are two of them. I meant updating it for `.navigation ul`. Answer is updated.